# Returning a Template from a Twig Extension

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a form that is placed on many pages of my site, and I wanted to write a Twig Extension to build and handle the form.  I thought that if I inject the Twig templating service and render a template with the form rendered, it would work.  But I got a circular reference.  My question is how to I return that template from the extension?

Comment: Could you post the codes you have done, yet?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the action that has the form:

```
public function formAction()
{
    //Code goes here with no difference from a regular action
    return $this->render('MyBundle:Base:form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Let's say `MyBundle:Base:form.html.twig` is a Twig template with all the markup you will need to render the form. Let's say the controller is in `MyBundle:Form:form`, and a template every page (but the form template) has, `MyBundle:Base:template.html.twig`. In that template, add the following line wherever you wish:

```
{{ render(controller('MyBundle:Form:form')) }}
```

That way you can "inject" whatever method you want in all of your pages. You would then set the action of the form to any controller action so it can process it properly.